# maximum download limit

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth, traffic

I'm writing software for bandwidth management in Linux. I use TC for bandwidth shaping, and it worked fine. I want to limit user bandwidth for a period of time. For example:

- For user 1, 100MB in a week

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [iptables quota module](http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.13) can be quite useful, too.

Answer (score 6):

You can add an iptables rule for each IP and use it to count the traffic that passed through the rule. Just add 2 rules for each IP:

```
 iptables -A FORWARD -s <ip>
 iptables -A FORWARD -d <ip>
```

And then you can get the results with `iptables -nv -L FOWARD` that will return something like this:

```
# iptables -nvL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

This one is zero but the `bytes` column will give you what you want I swear :)

After that all you need is a `cron` job to save those values, and to check if they are over the alloted bytes that week, then change the rules to block the traffic or use `tc` to throttle their bandwidth, or anything else.